# Problemas al verificar los lanzamientos de un dado en Java

Tags: java

Estoy creando un minijuego por la computadora en el que al iniciar automaticamente me imprima en consola los numeros que se repitieron al tirar 10 veces un dado. El problema por el que estoy aquí es que al verificar que se hayan lanzado todos, no me aparece los 10 lanzamientos. Esto lo verifico sumando las repeticiones de los 10 lanzamientos del dado (del 1 al 6).
Lo curioso es que a veces me daba la suma un 10, reiniciaba y me daba un 11, 9 o hasta números inferiores a los mencionados. Ayuda.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ciclos4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        int azar = aleatorio.nextInt( 10 ) - (0 + 1) + 1;
        int uno = 0, dos = 0, tres = 0, cuatro = 0, cinco = 0, seis = 0;
        int intentos = 0;
        for (int i = intentos; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (azar == 1) {
                uno++;
            } else if (azar == 2) {
                dos++;
            } else if (azar == 3) {
                tres++;
            } else if (azar == 4) {
                cuatro++;
            } else if (azar == 5) {
                cinco++;
            } else if (azar == 6) {
                seis++;
            }
            azar = aleatorio.nextInt( 6 ) - (0 + 1) + 1;
        }

        System.out.println( "Veces que se repitieron los números: " );
        System.out.println( "Numero 1: " + uno );
        System.out.println( "Numero 2: " + dos );
        System.out.println( "Numero 3: " + tres );
        System.out.println( "Numero 4: " + cuatro );
        System.out.println( "Numero 5: " + cinco );
        System.out.println( "Numero 6: " + seis );
    }
}
```

Y la salida es:

```
Veces que se repitieron los números:
Numero 1: 1
Numero 2: 4
Numero 3: 2
Numero 4: 1
Numero 5: 1
Numero 6: 0
```

Comment: El código se pone a texto para poder reproducir tu error. No se coloca a imágenes.

Comment: Por otro lado `random.nextInt(6)` te da un número entre 0 y 5 (incluyendo el 5). Simplemente súmale 1 para que te de un número entre 1 y 6. Actualmente le sumas uno y le restas uno, eso equivale a no hacer nada, es decir tendrás un número de 0 a 5. Obviamente cuando el número aleatorio es 0, el caso no es capturado por ningún `if`, y de ahí tus errores.

Comment: Por último quítale el menor igual (`<=`) al ciclo `for`. Usa `<`. Esa es la causa de que entres 11 veces al ciclo.

Comment: La primera asignación a azar va entre 0 y 9

Answer (score 1):

Con esta forma de generar el numero aleatorio y considerando así a la forma de controlar el número de veces que las sentencias dentro bloque de código son ejecutadas se verifican los 10 lanzamientos al compáralos  con los números generados Para la generación considerar que con random.nextInt(6) obtenemos valores entre 0 y 5 por eso se le suma el valor mas bajo deseado que es uno al valor obtenido.Entonces con random.nextInt(6)+1 obtenemos valores entre 1 y 6 [aleatorios dados](https://javiergarciaescobedo.es/programacion-en-java/27-estructuras-basicas-de-datos/96-numeros-aleatorios-en-java)

```
import java.util.Random;
// Use this editor to write, compile and run your Java code online

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int uno = 0;
    int dos = 0; 
    int tres = 0;
    int cuatro = 0;
    int cinco = 0;
    int seis = 0;
   
    Random rnd = new Random();
    
     int azar=rnd.nextInt(6)+1;;
        System.out.println(azar);
      
    for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++){
        if (azar == 1) {
                uno++;
            } else if (azar == 2) {
                dos++;
            } else if (azar == 3) {
                tres++;
            } else if (azar == 4) {
                cuatro++;
            } else if (azar == 5) {
                cinco++;
            } else if (azar == 6) {
                seis++;
            }
         azar=rnd.nextInt(6)+1;
        System.out.println(azar);
}

        System.out.println( "Numero 1: " + uno );
        System.out.println( "Numero 2: " + dos  );
        System.out.println( "Numero 3: " + tres );
        System.out.println( "Numero 4: " + cuatro );
        System.out.println( "Numero 5: " + cinco );
        System.out.println( "Numero 6: " + seis );
    }
}


// el primer valor generado fuera del ciclo lo compara
4
3
1
3
4
2
4
4
3
5
3// ultimo valor no lo compara
Numero 1: 1
Numero 2: 1
Numero 3: 3
Numero 4: 4
Numero 5: 1
Numero 6: 0
.....................
1// primer valor fuera ciclo compara
2
6
1
5
6
3
4
5
6
5// ultimo no lo compara
Numero 1: 2
Numero 2: 1
Numero 3: 1
Numero 4: 1
Numero 5: 2
Numero 6: 3
```

Vemos el valor inicial de azar y como se comporta el ciclo con esos limites
Vemos el resultado de iniciar a azar y el valor generado y no comparado

```
// el primer valor generado fuera del ciclo lo compara
    4
    3
    1
    3
    4
    2
    4
    4
    3
    5
    3// ultimo valor no lo compara
    Numero 1: 1
    Numero 2: 1
    Numero 3: 3
    Numero 4: 4
    Numero 5: 1
    Numero 6: 0
    .....................
    1// primer valor fuera ciclo compara
    2
    6
    1
    5
    6
    3
    4
    5
    6
    5// ultimo no lo compara
    Numero 1: 2
    Numero 2: 1
    Numero 3: 1
    Numero 4: 1
    Numero 5: 2
    Numero 6: 3
```